# what does the http type of position of AbstractSecurityFactory mean?

Tags: symfony

I read the document , it says: 
getPosition
Method which must be of type pre_auth, form, http, and remember_me and defines the position at which the provider is called. I understand pre_auth, form, remember_me, but the http type has no sense for me,   can anybody explain this in details please?

Comment: HTTP Authentication?

Comment: do you mean http basic authentication ? I don't think so.

Comment: No, I mean http something like api where you provide apikey in url.